# Change grain shell in saltstack from /bin/sh to /bin/bash

Tags: salt-stack

I was confused by grains in salt:

shell:  /bin/sh

In all my another server it is:

shell: /bin/bash

So, I got some troubles with PATH from scripts.

Please, how can I change  shell environemnt in grain?  Or, where salt gets it for grain?

all my users in this server has shell=/bin/bash.  default shell for useradd is /bin/bash

Comment: Please update what are _"some troubles with PATH from scripts"_. It is not clear whether problem and solution correspond (and whether value in grains is actually an issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Value for the `shell` key in `grains` is determined at minion start time by the file `grains/extra.py` in [the salt codebase](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/f0f512a4da0f14b319b36418b7360bd7a5953fdd/salt/grains/extra.py#L18). Salt looks for a `SHELL` environment variable of minion process (only) and defaults to `/bin/sh`.
- When it comes to user accounts, the shell is configured per account in `/etc/passwd`.

So, it is possible and normal that `SHELL` variable is different per user, per minion, ... and, ultimately, per any OS process.

Make sure `SHELL` is set to required value for minion process to get required grains value.